# How do I organize fields of apache solr for crm application

Tags: apache, solr

I want to integrate solr with my crm.

crm has morethan 20 modules like accounts,contacts,invoice,quotes,documents etc.

each module has morethan 25 fields.

I want to search on idividual modules and also all modules together.

How can I achieve this ?, by creating a type field and storing the module name for each record.

or creating a shard for each module is a right approach

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a separate `core` for every module.

This would limit help you to search faster as you will be searching in specific module/core.  Here every core will act as index/partition  sort of thing to your indexes. Instead of storing all the indexed data in one core, create a separate core and split the indexed data, which will help in faster retrieval.

I have different companies accessing there data in the system. Here I have created a separate core with the company name and which will held the data only for that company. When a `X` performs a search it will be performed in

```
http://hostname:8983/solr/X/search_criteria
```

You can have a separate field for module type which would distinguish of between the modules.

Or You can try creating different configuration for cores by creating different `schema.xml`

I have tried this earlier by creating a core with different configuration.

```
config=different_solrconfig.xml&schema=different_schema.xml
```

for more info check here [more info on core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin)

I am just not sure in the current version how it is working. You can read on it and take your decision...